# How to temporary disable the click function when it is executing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, jquery-events

```
$("#prevPage").live("click",function(e) {
.................
});
```

For example, when the user have already clicked on the `prevPage`, the statement inside it is running, if the user click on it instantly , it will trigger again. However, I would like the click event trigger only after all the statement inside it have finish execution, How to achieve that?

Comment: use .on() instead of .live() because .live() is deprecating..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this or something similar:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // disable command while function is being executed.
    var sample = { 
        isExecuting : 0, 
        doWork : function (e) { 
            if (sample.isExecuting === 1) return;
            sample.isExecuting = 1;
            // do work -- whatever you please
            sample.isExecuting = 0; // say: I'm done!
        }
    };
    // live or bind
    $("#prevPage").bind("click",function(e) {
         sample.doWork(e);
    });
</script>
```

simple 'shield' to block a multiple-call scenario.

Comment: what if there is asynchronous execution like `settimeout` , on "do work -- whatever you please" .

Comment: then you defer the "unflag" (sample.isExecuting = 0) until the operation completes.  Do you have a callback function in your async operation?

Comment: async ajax or worker? I will provide a code sample.  In all async scenarios, there is a moment where certain operations need to occur synchronously.  knowing where that applies is a prerequisite to application development. waiting on feedback

Answer (score 1):

Then set a flag on the element to check if it's clickable or not.

```
$("#prevPage").on("click",function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  //get the clickable attribute
  //if it's not existent, its undefined hence "false"
  var unclickable = this.unclickable;

  //if it's not unclickable (it's clickable)
  if(!unclickable){

    //make the flag unclickable
    this.unclickable = true;

    //do stuff

    //reset it back the way it was after operations
    this.unclickable = false;
  }


});
```

Answer (score 0):

use the unbind function of jquery

```
$("#prevPage").unbind("click");
```

after your task finished

```
$("#prevPage").bind("click",function(){....your code here....});
```

Comment: You should use [die](http://api.jquery.com/die/) but know that `live` and `die` have been **removed** in jQuery 1.9.

Comment: $("#prevPage").bind("click",function(){});

Answer (score 0):

Set a variable that your event triggered

```
var prevPageEventTriggered = false ;
```

and set it to `ture` when event triggered

```
prevPageEventTriggered = true;
```

and then add condition for this in click event handler function

```
$("#prevPage").live("click",function(e) {

        if ( prevPageEventTriggered ) {
                return false;
        }

        // your code goes here
        // ....
});
```

if it have finish execution, you can set it to `false` . hope this will helps

Answer (score 0):

- **unbind()** will do the work for you.
- An alternate could be like using **detach()**. When your process is executing detach the button and when your process finsihes executing, use **reattach()** to get the button back.
  What I will suggest is use **unbind()**.